# I killed my GUI and Startx cant find a "screen"

Tags: nvidia, xorg, 64-bit, gui

First off let me mention that this problem happened a while ago so i may have forgotten some of the details. A while ago I was trying to get used to backtrack5 and I was doing pretty well I think. I learned that you shouldn't be using root exclusively so i was creating a user account and trying to give it all the right  permissions and access.

I don't remember what did it specially but this is part of the error message I'm getting from Xorg.0.log:

```
(II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
    compiled for 4.0.2, module version = 1.0.0
    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
(EE) NVIDIA: Failed to load the NVIDIA kernel module. Please check your
(EE) NVIDIA:     system's kernel log for additional error messages.
(II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
(II) Unloading /usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
(EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module-specific error, 0)
(EE) No drivers available.

Fatal server error:
no screens found
```

Now knowing that this was a problem of my own doing I took a look at my history to try and figure out what i did wrong but i'm not very savvy in such things... I'll paste some of the relevant command history

[My Pasted command history](http://pastie.org/3284078)

I have an idea of what the problem might be but i have no idea how i would fix it. if anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated. And if i should provide anymore information just let me know.

PS sorry if this is a bit verbose. And sorry that the command history isn't formatted properly for this site.

Comment: Sounds as if you need to install the nvidia driver https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Comment: I checked that out and it almost seems reasonable but those are instructions for GUI. I have to do everything from the CLI. do you know how i would do that?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

Answer (score 19):

I feel like an idiot. After months of forum joining, hopping, posting and prowling I finally found the answer

```
rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
reboot
startx
```

That was it. But thanks for the help, guys.

Comment: anyone knows why removing `xorg.conf` solves the problem? I just spent hours trying to fix and removing this file just solved everything. Such stupidity.

Comment: I did the same just now and indeed, that solved my issue. xorg-server starts fine; I don't have mouse and keyboard input but I know how to resolve that issue. It's really annoying that the people who wrote xorg-server and the other parts, don't add such simple troubleshooting aids - the askubuntu.com site helped more than the xorg-hackers did here ...

Comment: This solved my problem. In my case, I had switched the storage device (SSD) from a computer with Nvidia graphics to one with intel and after installing the intel drivers and deleting the Nvidia drivers, I had the login loop and would only login in recovery mode until I deleted the `/etc/x11/xorg.conf`

Answer (score 1):

To install the nvidia driver from the command line use

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Then reboot, X should start. If needed,  you then run `nvidia-settings` to make any adjustments. Run it as root to save your settings

```
gksu nvidia-settings
```

Answer (score 1):

To the folks experiencing this issue, but with ATI drivers, see the following

https://askubuntu.com/a/225563/515315

basically:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo Xorg -configure
sudo cp /home/XXXXXXX/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: I just ran the command. Now even virtual terminal is not coming.

Answer (score 0):

The following solved the issue for me on Ubuntu 22:

`rm /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`

Then run

`sudo X -configure`