# How do I install the X.org Radeon/ATI driver?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, xorg, compiling

I recently downloaded version 7 of the Radeon/ATI X.org Driver from this link: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/driver/xf86-video-ati

My question is how do I compile and install it? I don't like using the offical AMD/ATI Driver.

Ubuntu Version is 12.10

Comment: what version of ubuntu do you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go into your terminal and type:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
>
> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati

If you want the stable releases (it would still help if you said what version of ubuntu you're running.):

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
>
> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati

**To build from git**

If you are feeling adventurous, follow [these](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/DriverBuilding) instructions and they should work for you.

Comment: Is this repository a stable one or unstable?

Comment: @TeddyThorpe no see update. I have linked to a stable one for you too but the one you actually requested is in the edgers repo. That means the version you request is not yet stable either. If you're unsure, maybe try the stable driver and see how you get on.

Answer (score -1):

In order to install file which you have downloaded from the site, extract the content if it was zip file, then right click >> select properties >> In the permissions tab , check the Allow executing file as a program.